# when the memory used by thread stack was freed

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack, free

I am observing the connection of mongoDB.  when a new connction generated, I can see a new thread created ( pstack ·pgrep monnod`| grep -c Thread),  and some new chunks memory allocated (get from /proc/`pgrep mongod`/maps),  one of the chunk is 1024K, which should be the stack size for the new thread, I saw it was set to 1024k in the code.
 when I exited this session, the No. of threads decrease by 1, but the memory still there.  when I generate a new connection, these memory seems reused. so I guess it should be the behavior of linux Kernel. 
 Can I konw if I am right? and where is this feature well documented? 
 thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I exited this session, the No. of threads decrease by 1, but the memory still there. when I generate a new connection, these memory seems reused. so I guess it should be the behavior of linux Kernel.

This has nothing to do with the kernel.

GLIBC will `mmap` thread stack, and has a cache of such stacks. The code is [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/nptl/allocatestack.c#l173).